# Is a child holding a UK passport issued in 2015 eligible for Visa Waiver Program to the US?

Tags: usa

A child is the holder of a UK passport that was issued in 2015. Are they eligible for the USA's Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: Why do you suspect he might not be? Are you concerned about something inherent to the passport itself? Has the child previously overstayed in the USA? Does the child have a criminal record or known connections to terrorist groups?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't think overstay is relevant for children: it's recognized that they're usually not capable of leaving independently of their parents.

Comment: Is this a trick question of some sort and the answer is "no, because the child I'm speaking about is also a citizen of Iran, ha ha, don't make so many assumptions"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes, I know, but the OP may not know that and it is plausible that that is why they are asking. We simply do not *know*.

Answer (score 3):

As a general guide, to enter the USA using the VWP a British passport must:
- describe the holder’s nationality as a ‘British Citizen’
- be an ePassport.
Additionally the traveller must have received authorisation from the Electronic System for Travel Authorisation (ESTA) https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/

Full guidance is available here https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements

Comment: ESTA isn't required if entering by land, so someone who is entering by land should pay more attention to the specific entry requirements that the ESTA application asks about.  These are discussed on the UK page you link to; official US sources include the VWP pages of the [Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) and of [Customs and Border Protection](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program).